# background image doesn t fit contain

Tags: reactjs

backgorund image responsive but
if i make smaller it vertically  breaks the content
it vertically  breaks the content somecomment[almclasmclnsalvnlanslcnlsanclsanclnsalcnlsanclsacsanclsanclnascnlasncla]

```
import useMediaQuery from "@/hooks/useMediaQuery";

type Props = {};

const home = (props: Props) => {
  const isAboveMediumScreens = useMediaQuery("(min-width: 1300px)");
  return (
    <section className="">
      <div className="  min-h-screen  bg-markusbg bg-contain bg-top bg-no-repeat  ">
        {/* MAIN HEADING */}
        <div className="">
          {/* HEADING */}
          <div className="  ">
            {/* TEXTS */}
            <div className="relative"></div>
          </div>

          {/* HEADING */}
          <div>
            {/* TEXTS */}
            <div
              className="absolute flex basis-3/5 justify-center md:z-10
              md:ml-40 md:mt-16 md:justify-items-end"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default home;
```

[it s look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDez6.png)

[i want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfzUn.png)

Comment: Are you using Tailwind or a different CSS system? Adding an appropriate tag would likely get the right eyes.